# Maximal (among non-principal ideals) Ideal Must be Prime

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> If $I$ is an ideal which is maximal among the ones that are not principal, then $I$ is prime.

This would mean that for all $f \in R$, $(f) \subset I$. Could I then use colon ideals? I was thinking maybe that for $P$ prime, $(P: (f) )= R$ if $f \in P$ or $(P: (f) )= P$ if $f \not\in P$.

Comment: No, it wouldn't mean what you say it would...maximal doesn't mean that.

Comment: All the possible principal ideals be (f) where f is any element of R, correct? Then would it be that if I is maximal, then $I \subset (f)$ implies $(f)=R$?

Comment: Yes @violin.lover, that last you wrote is true...if you actually meant $\;I\subset (f)\;,\;\;I\neq (f)\;$ . Still, my first comment remains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much the same answer I gave to your other question ([Maximal Ideal Must be Prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723143/maximal-ideal-must-be-prime)).

This time, you'll need to prove that $J = I + (f)$ is not principal if $J$ is not principal.  The method of proof is pretty much the same.

Comment: "*The method of proof is pretty much the same.*" If you embrace a large view, then this is true, but the proof in this case is a little more tricky. (-1)

Comment: @chriseur What do you mean by J=I+(f) is not principal if J is not Principal